# Exception throwed but not catched

Tags: java, exception

I can't figure out why... I have 2 exceptions throwed but I cannot catch them.

In a lib I have this piece of code which throws 2 different kinds of exception.

```
try {
    statement = con.prepareStatement(query);
    if (statement.executeUpdate() != 1) {
        throw new InvalidIndexException("Record not found or not modified", query);
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new DatabaseIOException(e, "", "SQL Error", logQuery);
}
```

The query is modified to trigger an SQL error. When it occurs I have one log entry:

```
2013-04-26 12:19:39 class database.DatabaseIOException
userManagement.Login.setActivationFlag(Login.java:473) 
-> SQL Error
[QUERY]: UPDATE login SET activationprTTTTocess='false' WHERE  id=235423432
[MSG]: ERROR: column "activationprttttocess" of relation "login" does not exis
```

So I'm sure that the sqlerror has been captured and re-thrown as *DatabaseIOException*, I followed the code execution in debug-mode with Netbeans too. All rigth for now.

Now I have a servlet where I try to activate an user:

```
try{
   Login.setActivationFlag(235423432, false);
} catch (DatabaseIOException db) {
   Log.addItem(db.getMessage());
} catch (InvalidIndexException ed){
   Log.addItem(ed.getMessage());
}
```

Wathewer I try there is no way to enter in any catch block. When the *Login.setActivationFlag* line is executed the error appears on the log (as shown above) but the catch blocks are skipped like nothing is appened.

I cannot figure out why this weird behaviour. I'm using these exceptions since 3 years without any issue... 
There must be something really stupid about this code that I cannot see....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After about 4 hours of debugging I found out what it was: the worse thing to do when working with exceptions.

In the *setActivationFlag()* the **return** statement was misplaced... it fell in the **finally block**.

```
...
   } finally {
      ...
      return done;
   }
}
```

instead of

```
...
   } finally {
       ...
   }
   return done;
}
```

EDIT:
Here a piece of code to test

```
public void ExceptionTest() throws Exception {
    try {
        Integer test = null;
        test.toString();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        out.println("Catched inner NullPointerException");
            throw new Exception("My Exception", e);
    } finally {
        return;
    }
}

public void test() {
    try {
        ExceptionTest();
    } catch (Exception outer) {
        out.println("Catched: " + outer.getMessage());
    }
}
```

With the **return** statement in the *finally* block the outer exception is never caught.

Comment: So how could anybody have helped?

Comment: Mostly depends on search keys. This error is quite notorious but hard to detect. I modified the title hoping this will be more representative.

Comment: The issue is that you didn't include any code that could help diagnose the issue. I'd argue that your solution doesn't make any sense given your claims in the question--if the code threw an exception the return from the finally block doesn't matter anyway, the exception would still be thrown, and be catchable.

Comment: Better now with the example? In this case the exception is not catchable.

Answer (score -1):

Are you catching the same type of DatabaseIOException? If there is an exception in a different namespace with the same name, and autocompletion 'helps' by importing that class, you'd get the behavior you describe.